# npm install issue with meteor custom deployment

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm-install

I have used `meteor build` command to create a deployment bundle `.tar.gz` which is plain Node.js application.

I extract bundle and run following command to run app:

```
cd programs/server && npm install
```

But i am not available to run npm install, it is returning message 'SampleApplication module is not defined' and 'sampleapplication' is name of my application.

Comment: What kind of OS is your server running? Does it have capitalization sensitivity.

Comment: windows and no it does not have capitalization sentitivity.

Answer (score 0):

Given the error you posted, and the limited information available, I assume you're experiencing capitalization sensitivity from whatever OS your deployment server is on. Windows, Linux, OSX all handle capitalization in file paths differently.

Thus, if you develop on OSX which does not care about capitalization and deploy to a windows server which treats file paths as is you can run into issues with required file paths in your program if you are not careful.

Comment: i developed app on windows machine and deploying in another windows machine. both machine has same configurations.

Comment: Are you positive they do? Check your node + npm versions on your local vs the server:
In terminal type node -v.

Comment: Node - 4.6.1, npm -3.10.9.

Comment: Both are the same local and deployment ?